# How to take a hot backup from a database SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-backups

Is it possible to take a HOT backup from a database SQL Server EXPRESS (2012 or less) by using C# code?

I've seen this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/461494/Backing-up-an-SQL-Database-in-Csharp) but it doesn't seem to be usable for a HOT backup.

Another solution might be to execute the query "Backup Database ... to disk ..."; how would I launch that?

Comment: You would "launch" it just like any other query. The BACKUP DATABASE is just a command in tsql that you execute.

Comment: That article looks like it does a "hot" backup just fine. That is, it doesn't need to take the db offline to do the backup.

Comment: @Ben Thul: The remark in the header of the function BackupDatabase is "The database must NOT be in use when backing up"

Comment: This is a case, though where the comments doing match the code. Using the code provided will produce a transactionally consistent backup even if the database is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

You can make a call to the backup command in SQL to make a hot backup `BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO  DISK = N'mydb.BAK' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT`

Which will write a file to disk.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO  DISK = N'mydb.BAK' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT", connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Is it possible to launch it by using a DB context (entity framework) and asynchronously ?